# How to pattern match records in OCaml?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, record

I have the following data type (please ignore the fact that this could be way more simple)

```
type tKey = Key of int;;

type tBST = Null | Pos of node ref
        and node = {mutable key : tKey; 
            mutable left : tBST; 
            mutable right : tBST};;
```

I am having the following error with this function which looks like my pattern matching is not right

```
let rec string_of_tree = function
    Null -> "()"
    | Pos (ref {key; left = Null; right = Null}) -> Printf.sprintf "(%s)" (string_of_root (root tree))
    | Pos (ref {key; left; right}) -> Printf.sprintf "(%s %s %s)" 
                            (string_of_root (root tree)) 
                            (string_of_tree (leftLeaf tree)) 
                            (string_of_tree (rightLeaf tree));;

Error: Syntax error: ')' expected
Error: This '(' might be unmatched
```

Error refers to the following parenthesis: (ref {key; ( ... )})

Comment: you should probably split your match expression in two, so that the first one only deals wih the `Null` and  `Pos` tags, and the second one works on the *referenced value* in the `Pos` case, rather than matching the whole `ref`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match against a reference, you can't use `ref`. `ref` isn't a constructor, it's really just a function that makes a reference. To match against a reference you can use `{ contents = ... }`

Unfortunately this will make the code even more dense :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you try to pattern match with `ref`, which is really just sugar for a record containing a mutable `contents`field`.

Try replacing

```
| Pos (ref { ... }) -> ...
```

with

```
| Pos { contents = { ... }} -> ...
```